# Get Data from Url

Tags: php

I used **http build query** to send data from URL 
The Url is in the following format :

```
http://www.abc.in/xyz/Tak-Wadi?0%5Bmerchant_location_id%5D=1&1%5Bmerchant_location_id%5D=2
```

Now How to get data ie. merchant_location_id 1 & 2.

Comment: What do you mean "How to get data?" If you are using http_build_query, surely you already know the values?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
echo $id1 = $_GET[0]['merchant_location_id'];
echo $id2 = $_GET[1]['merchant_location_id'];
```

Comment: URL is like : 
http://www.abc.in/xyz/Tak-Wadi?0[merchant_location_id]=1&1[merchant_location_id]=2, 

hence 0 and 1 is array, and 'merchant_location_id' will be key.

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryString = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $queryString[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$queryString = implode('&', $queryString);
```

For further assistance you can get reference from [this weblink](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/08/17/php-fetch-get-as-string-with-http_build_query/).

Answer (score 0):

if you do the following:

```
$url = urldecode("http://www.abc.in/xyz/Tak-Wadi?0%5Bmerchant_location_id%5D=1&1%5Bmerchant_location_id%5D=2");

echo $url;
```

That will clear it up a bit:

```
http://www.abc.in/xyz/Tak-Wadi?0[merchant_location_id]=1&1[merchant_location_id]=2
```

Now, this url let's you know that you've got two arrays each containing one key (`merchant_location_id`)

```
$_GET[0]
$_GET[1]
```

Now that we know this it's easy to retrieve the data.

```
echo $_GET[0]['merchant_location_id'];
echo $_GET[1]['merchant_location_id'];
```

That should be all there is to it.